# Where's My Profile Picture?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture

I can't see my profile picture anymore! This happens in every site that I joined (other than Meta.SE and Area 51 (where I have an default avatar)).

Look here as my picture is replaced by a white frame:
[image]

This has to be a bug because.. well, it never happened before. I like my profile picture, and it is kinda annoying to see that a white frame is now my official profile picture. My real profile picture is a soccer ball with multiple country flags in the pentagons. So why did my profile picture just disappeared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to have been some corruption to your profile image URL on Stack Overflow (possibly from a short lived bug where these URLs were saved as schemaless and whene rendered ended up getting a `file` schema - thanks to the `Uri` class... - if saved like that... no profile image).

I re-saved you profile with the `http` schema on the url, and all is well in the world.