# Profile Picture Bug - Picture Dosen't Show Up on any Stack Exchange Menu Bar

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, menu-bar

I am having a [similar issue to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253117/wheres-my-profile-picture) with my profile picture not showing up on any of the stack exchange communities that I am a member of.
[image: Screenshot of my meta stack exchange toolbar.]

I know this is not a huge concern but it is an issue that I have encountered.
Does anyone know if this is something that I can fix this  easily or is this a bug that needs to be addressed?

## UPDATE

I have reuploaded a different image to my profile and fixed my original issue! Now I have a much worse one!

[image: Broken Profile Picture]

Comment: @bjb568 not really, That other one is marked status-completed. (Though I'm going to flag it for removal of the wrong tag, as it keeps happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange issue that I have just encountered.

## What I Did:

Re-uploaded the same JPG image again to my profile through the standard Stack Exchange edit profile user interface (twice). I still had the same issue.

Uploaded a new JPG image created using Photoshop. This did fix the original issue I was having but introduced a much bigger one! My 48x48 pixel image was displaying fine but the large image on my profile page had an issue (see image in the update).

Re-uploaded the original image to return my profile back to its original state, saves the changes and every image was back to normal.

---

I'd love to know if anyone else had this issue! I hope this helps someone.

Comment: It happened to me few weeks ago, but only with the 48x48 version, and fixed by re-uploading once, so really not sure what's going on with yours.

Comment: Yes, I guess mine was some sort of anomaly and that your solution will probably work for most people.

Answer (score 2):

Just re-upload your picture. This is a bug on imgur side, result of some corruption on their side while saving the thumbnails.

The corrupted thumbnail is the 48x48 pixels one:

[image]

Note that other thumbnails, e.g. the [328x328 pixels one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC19D.jpg?s=328&g=1) are fine.

I fear there's no way to fix it, just create new set of thumbnails by uploading the picture again.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. It a shame that its not something that they can be bothered to fix to avoid this sort of thing happening in the future

Comment: @Max well, with thousands of pictures uploaded daily, it happens only for few, most likely less than 1% - so guess not worth spending too much time on this (from imgur dev team point of view) as long as it's easily fixed by re-uploading the same picture.

Comment: Oh right! That is fair enough I didn't realise I was part of such a vast minority

Comment: I have reuploaded my picture twice but the 48x48 remains largely grayed out as it was before - will it take some time for the changes to take effect?

Comment: @Max no you did not re-upload, it's still "LC19D.jpg" - to re-upload go [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), click "Change picture" then "Upload new picture".

Comment: that is exactly what I did, I was reuploading with the same pisture before but now its a different file entirely! New jpg straight from photoshop and still I have the same problem

Comment: @Max huh, now that's weird. Looks like you found "imgur killer"... probably something in your picture is choking their code. Wish I could help you further, but probably only a dev (SE, or imgur) can dig into this deeper.

Comment: thanks for your advise it has helped a lot in allowing me to fix this weird bug! Finally!